# Post image and text to Twitter through Twitter native app in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I am working on twitter integration so is there any way or twitter api
to post image and text to twitter through twitter native app in iOS programmatically.
 
I can post text message by opening native app using below code

```
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://post?message=hello%20world&"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:postURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:postURL];
    }
```

but I am not able to post image to twitter through twitter native app ?

Please any one can help me to sort out these problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ve you used social framework in xcode?

Comment: yes, i used social and twitter framework in my app.

Comment: you can use SLComposeViewController to upload image and text which will show you an popup

Comment: My requirement is to post image and text to twitter through native twitter app.

Comment: Are you sure Twitter supports this through openURL ?

Comment: It will not support so any other solutions from your side ?